# Duplicate Information

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a df that contains the columns, [CPF, name, age].
I need to find the CPF that is repeated on the base and return the person's name together with the CPF.
So far I've done that.

```
    TrueDuplicat = base.groupby(['CPF']).size().reset_index(name='count')
    TrueDuplicat = TrueDuplicat[TrueDuplicat['count']>1]
```

When I put:

```
    TrueDuplicat = TrueDuplicat[['name','CPF']]
```

I get the error "['name'] not in index".

How do I get the duplicate CPF with the person's name?

Exemplo do DF

```
CPF         name  age

38445675455  Alex  15

54785698574  Ana   25

38445675455  Bento 22

65878584558  Caio  33
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the dataframe that reproduces this error.

Comment: I do not understand, the sample is the dataframe's own information or the error?

Comment: A sample of the dataframe, that when we run this code will give the error you report.

Comment: May I also ask, what exactly does this question have to do with the `[excel]` tag?

Comment: Rawrplus is that the Df file comes from Excel

Comment: @A.Leistra 
edit the comment by putting an example of how Df is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `groupby`, you do not have a `name` column in `TrueDuplicat`.  For the example you have posted, `TrueDuplicat` is:

```
           CPF  count
0  38445675455      2
```

If you're looking for the names corresponding to the CPF values in `TrueDuplicat`, you can do something like

```
df[df['CPF'].isin(TrueDuplicat['CPF'].tolist())]
```

which, for your example, will yield

```
           CPF   name  age
0  38445675455   Alex   15
2  38445675455  Bento   22
```